# Get the instance of the object that created a class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to get the instance of the class that created the class?

For example I have the following example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private GameObject initiator;

    public MyClass(){
        initiator = // Get the value here
    }
}
```

This class then creates a `new MyClass` and `initiator` from above and stores the instance of `MyInitiator` in `initiator`.

```
public class MyInitiator : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        new MyClass();
    }
}
```

I know that I can pass `this` as a parameter or create a property and set it that way, but I would like to avoid having to do that, and have it do it automatically or with some sort of logic within `MyClass` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any other way than the two you have suggested.

I would do it as a constructor parameter with `this` and use a method to create a new instance, like so:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private GameObject initiator;

    public MyClass(GameObject initiator)
    {
        this.initiator = initiator;
    }
}

public class MyInitiator : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        MyClass first = NewMyClass();
        MyClass second = NewMyClass();
        // ...
    }

    private MyClass NewMyClass()
    {
        return new MyClass(this);
    }
}
```